# Node.js imagemin on CentOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, centos6, libpng, imagemin

I am trying to use **Node.js imagemin** to compress a lot of images on my server. I like using **imagemin** because I know how to point it at specific directories.

I am using CentOS 6 and when I run my file, I get the error:

> node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found

Also, when I installed **imagemin** with `npm install imagemin`, I got an error that said:

> Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed

Any ideas on what I can do to solve this?

Comment: It seems that you don't have `libpng-dev` installed. On CentOS, `yum install libpng-dev` should install it (not 100% sure about package name).

Comment: That did it. I was trying that earlier but I couldn't find the package initially so I thought it didn't exist on CentOS. It was named libpng-devel. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Problem de facto already solved in the comments - but for the sake of completion and future generations I'm posting an actual answer).

> Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed

This error means that the system is lacking `libpng` development library, which is needed to install `imagemin` Node.JS module. To install it on CentOS 6, you need to issue this command:

`yum install libpng-devel`

Please note that both package manager (here - `yum`) and package name (`libpng-devel`) can vary between different Linux distributions.

Comment: Same problem appear with CentOS 7 with `libpng-devel` installed, version **1.5.13-7**.

Comment: I have found a solution afterwards and I have shared it as a separate answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue with CentOS 7 even with `libpng-devel` installed. It seems the package carries a precompiled binary program in `node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant` which is somehow incompatible with the Linux installation (CentOS 7 latest).

I have made a solution to the problem by replacing this binary file with the one that is available for CentOS 7.

I am installing the official package `pngquant` with `yum`, first. Then I am installing the node modules. You can remove the `node_modules` folder if you like prior to install action. Its not required, though.

The error will be shown as usual (the program file is not yet replaced):

> `` ⚠ The `node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
>     ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed
>     ℹ compiling from source
>     ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
>       at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5) ``

**However, after replacing the binary file everything should be fine.**

`sh
yum install libpng-devel pngquant
npm install
rm -rf node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant
ln -s /usr/bin/pngquant node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant`

After that you can run any command you like, "imagemin:dynamic", etc. It should work properly.

### Summary

Generally speaking, the problem appear to be inside the `pngquant-bin` node package. This solution might help for other Linux distributions as well.

The solution itself is to install the **officially supported version** of `pngquant` with the OS package manager and to replace the binary inside the `pngquant-bin` vendor folder after its installation.

## Update

In addition, there is a recent problem that is still related with `pngquant` npm package. It seems that there is a buggy release of it - lock the required `pngquant` package in your `package.json` to older version (last properly running version for you).

Answer (score 6):

The previous solutions didn't work for me. I'm using centos 7.4

When executing executing

```
# npm install
```

I recieved the error:

> ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed`

While trying to install `libpng-devel`, it says it's already installed.

**Solution**

Update the nodejs & npm version if it's using old one.

I have updated to

**Nodejs Version**

```
[root@hosting ~]# node -v
```

v8.10.0

npm version

```
[root@hosting ~]# npm -v
```

5.7.1

Check the installed libpng-devel on your server.

```
[root@hosting ~]# rpm -qa |grep libpng
```

libpng-1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64

libpng-devel-1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64

If you are using epel repo then it will install the latest version. For more libpng release check

```
[root@hosting ~]# yum list |grep libpng
```

I have installed

```
yum install libpng12-1.2.50-10.el7.x86_64 libpng12-devel-1.2.50-10.el7.x86_64
```

moved node modules

```
mv node_modules node_modules_bak
```

Then type

```
# npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I'm using a CentOS instance on Amazon WS and I faced same problem here. I solved it by installing libpng12 and libpng12-devel (yum install libpng12 libpng12-devel), then running yarn install (or npm install) and the packages did installed correctly.

Just this!

Comment: AWS CodeBuild - it worked! This answer should have more points.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I resolved the issue for my case:

Delete `node_modules`:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Install following dependencies:

```
sudo dnf install libpng-devel pngquant gcc make libpng12 libpng12-devel
```

Rebuild dependencies. I use `yarn`:

```
yarn
```